# Nginx reverse proxy - passthrough basic authenication

Tags: nginx, iis, reverse-proxy, http-basic-authentication

I am trying to setup nginx as a reverse rpoxy server in front off several IIS web servers who are authenticating using Basic authentication.

(note - this is not the same as [nginx providing the auth using a password file](http://www.howtoforge.com/basic-http-authentication-with-nginx) - it should just be marshelling everythnig between the browser/server)

Its working kind off - but getting repeatedly prompted for auth by every single resource (image/css etc) on a page.

```
upstream my_iis_server {
      server 192.168.1.10;
}

server {
    listen       1.1.1.1:80;
    server_name  www.example.com;  

    ## send request back to my iis server ##
    location / {
     proxy_pass  http://my_iis_server;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_http_version      1.1;
     proxy_pass_header       Authorization;     
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think nginx is blocking request headers and not sending them to IIS. Try setting

```
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
```

on your location block.

Greetings.

Comment: Isn't that the default value, if `proxy_pass_request_headers` is not set? That's what the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?&_ga=2.7535218.1113392790.1679580365-1918377061.1679319530#proxy_pass_request_headers) says at least.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need

auth_basic off
in the areas that you don't want to do authentication on.

Comment: Thats for use when ningx is doing the auth itself (not for passthrough to upstream server) which I am not doing as explained in the question.